# Loop through Array with conditional output based on key/value pair

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array with the following columns:

- Task
- Status

I would like to print out a table that shows a list of the Tasks, but not the Status column. Instead, for Tasks where the Status = 0, I want to add a tag `<del>` to make the completed task be crossed out. Here's my current code:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val){
if ($key != 'Status') print "<td>$val</td>";
else if ($val == '0') print "<td><del>$val</del></td>";
}
```

This seems to be correct, but when I print it out, it prints all the tasks with the `<del>` tag. So basically the "else" clause is being run every time.

Here is the var_dump($row):

```
array
  'Task' => string 'Task A' (length=6)
  'Status' => string '3' (length=1)
array
  'Task' => string 'Task B' (length=6)
  'Status' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump( $row);`

Comment: Include your $row in your question and we can probably help a lot more.

Comment: OK - just added it to the question at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating as a key/value pair, try iterating with just the element itself and checking the individual indexes:

```
foreach ($row as $task) {
    $value = ($task['Status'] == '0') ? '<del>' . $task['Task'] . '</del>' : $task['Task'];
    echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
```